# How I use ReactDOM.findDOMNode() in react for front-end on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

```
var SearchForm = React.createClass({
  handleSearch: function() {
    alert('sd');
    var query = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.query).value;

    alert(query);
    var self = this;
    alert('Dom');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/events/search',
      data: { query: query },
      success: function(data) {
        self.props.handleSearch(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Search error: ', status, xhr, error);
      }
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <input onChange={this.handleSearch}
             type="text"
             className="form-control"
             placeholder="Type search phrase here..."
             ref="query" />
    )
  }
});
```

It's content of search_form.js.jsx
But if I run the app, ReactDOM.findDOMNode() doesn't work.
So therefore, alert(query) doesn't rise up.

Who answer to me?

Comment: have you imported var ReactDOM=require('react-dom');??

Comment: also check your console from browser and see what is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you're not using the state or props (in this case you'd lift up the state). One possible solution would be to add the query value as part of the state and change it on each change event. You can find a code example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/84512/)

```
var SearchForm = React.createClass({
 getInitialState() {
 return {
    query: ''
 }
},

...

render: function() {
 return(
   <input onChange={this.handleSearch}
         type="text"
         className="form-control"
         placeholder="Type search phrase here..."
         value={this.state.query} />

 )
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be this.refs not this.ref

```
var query = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.query).value;
```

you can also try to get the value directly:

```
var query = this.refs.query.value;
```

Comment: Sorry, the initial code is like var query = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.query).value; But it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But  "var query = this.refs.query.value;" doesn't work.another method?